# Command 'gcc' failed when trying to pip install mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to install `mysql-python` on my VM which is running CentOS 7.

When I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -m64
    _mysql.c:44:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
     #include "my_config.h"
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-qn5NTO/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-yi1zuo/
```

**Steps I've tried:**

```
sudo yum -y install python-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel mysql-devel
```

Still isn't working!

Comment: This error is not about gcc, it is saying that specific MySQL header file is not found. You need to install mysql-devel or mariadb-devel package.

Comment: But i did install mysql-devel